# Use the :hover selector to alter the rules of deep children elements with pure CSS

Tags: css, hover, children

Take a look at this element structure.

```
[#parent]
  [#childA]
    [#childChildA]
    [#childChildB]
      [#childChildChildA]
  [#childB]
[/#parent]
```

I want to change `#childChildChildA` to `opacity: 0`; by using the #childA :hover selector. I tried:

```
#childA:hover > #childChildB > #childChildChildA {
  opacity: 0 !important;
}
```

But this accomplished nothing. How can I modify a deep child element when using a much higher up parent element with pure CSS?

Comment: @DavidThomas, Amazingly that solution worked. Thanks a ton! Go ahead and post that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to remove the >'s

```
<div id='a'>
    <div id='b'></div>
    <div id='c'>
        <div id='d'></div>
    </div>
</div>


#a:hover #c #d {
  opacity: 0 !important;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qDRwa/

This  is an example of it with different id names.

Comment: Thanks. This is a more useful answer so I'll accept this one in a few minutes. Just a note that in this case I only need `#b:hover #d {}`

Comment: You are correct that is a more simplified answer. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest the following, albeit (obviously) untested (given the lack of HTML with which to work):

```
#childA:hover #childChildChildA {
    opacity: 0;
}
```